# How do I plug all the pipes?

Tags: mario-luigi-superstar-saga

I have to fix the plumbing in Beanbag Castle before I can meet the queen. Most of it I can figure out, but there is one room with 4 plugs that is baffling me. I hit the first one, and then I understand I have three more hits to close them all, but since some pop open every time, I can't figure it out. What order do I have to hit them in to get them all closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this fan walkthrough on GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/914980-mario-and-luigi-superstar-saga/faqs/28142):

> Here, you don't even need to guess at the first part, a Spin Jump, but then
>   comes the REAL pain! You can only use the hammer four times to hit the leaks,
>   so therefore, you must hit the leaks in a particular order.
>
> In this order, hit the leaks; Upper-left, Lower-left, upper-right, and then the
>   lower-right leak. After you apply yourself to this, the yellow and black
>   platform will suddenly rise with gushing water, so, two High Jumps and you're
>   off into the next room!

Comment: Here's a playthrough on YouTube that shows what to do: https://youtu.be/PRqIu9EfB4s?t=9m57s (Be careful watching it because the second half of the video spoils the boss fight, which involves several spoilers at once!)

Comment: That worked! I wasn't sure if the remake was the same as the original in this regard, but it looks like it is :)